# Accessing Private Final Static Double from Another Class

Tags: java, class

I am trying to access a private final static double from another class.

Here is the class:

```
public class coolMath{

private final static double alpha = 5.87;

public coolMath(){

}

public static double calDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2));     
        return dist;
    }

}
```

I need to access the variable alpha in another class. Is this possible? Does something need to happen in the constructor to make it available? Any ideas?

Comment: You're not trying to change Math.PI or something are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make `alpha` a public field or provide a `public static double getAlpha()` that returns it.

If you make the field public, you access it like so `double a = coolMath.alpha`.

Otherwise, `double a = coolMath.getAlpha();`

I strongly suggest you go through java modifiers again.

Comment: Ok, made it public, misread my java book. How can I access it? I've tried MyMath.alpha, but its not a method, as well as just trying alpha.

Comment: `coolMath.alpha` should work fine. Since your field is static, i presume you don't want to access it in instances of `coolMath`? Just a remark: By convention Java class names start with upper letters.

Answer (score 0):

This could technically be possible through some esoteric reflection methods, but I highly discourage it. It's better to change the visibility of your `alpha` variable or write some method that returns it (or perhaps sets it, if you need that also (but not if your var is `final`)).